# Problems to find a suitable formulation for a constraint

Tags: integer-programming, constraints, binary-programming

I have the following problem. I would like to model the following relationship. I have three binary variables $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$. These become either 0 or 1. I need a constraint for a mathemstical optimization model that expresses the following. Here, y=0 is to become if only one of the three x variables takes the value 1. If two of the x variables take the value 1, then y=1 should hold and also if none of the x variables take the value 1. How can I formulate the whole thing?

EDIT: $x_2$ and $x_3$ can never both be $=1$ at the same time. Either both are 0 or only one $=1$. $x_1$ can always take any value independently.

Comment: What if $\sum_i x_i = 3$?  Can $y$ take either value in that case?

Comment: I forgot to mention that $x_2$ and $x_3$ can never both be $=1$ at the same time. Either both are $=0$ or only one $=1$. $x_1$ can always take any value independently. But in that case, yes it can take either value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to enforce six logical implications:
\begin{align}
(x_1 \land \lnot x_2 \land \lnot x_3) &\implies \lnot y \tag1\label1 \\
(\lnot x_1 \land x_2 \land \lnot x_3) &\implies \lnot y \tag2\label2 \\
(\lnot x_1 \land \lnot x_2 \land x_3) &\implies \lnot y \tag3\label3 \\
(x_1 \land \lnot x_2 \land x_3) &\implies y \tag4\label4 \\
(x_1 \land x_2 \land \lnot x_3) &\implies y \tag5\label5 \\
(\lnot x_1 \land \lnot x_2 \land \lnot x_3) &\implies y \tag6\label6
\end{align}
You can derive linear constraints somewhat automatically by rewriting in conjunctive normal form.  For example, \eqref{1} yields
$$
\lnot (x_1 \land \lnot x_2 \land \lnot x_3) \lor \lnot y \\
\lnot x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3 \lor \lnot y \\
(1-x_1)+x_2+x_3+(1-y) \ge 1 \\
-x_1+x_2+x_3-y \ge -1
$$
The other five are similar, although you can strengthen \eqref{4} and \eqref{5} by using the fact that $x_2 + x_3 \le 1$.  Explicitly, \eqref{4} yields
$$
\lnot (x_1 \land \lnot x_2 \land x_3) \lor y \\
\lnot x_1 \lor x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor y \\
(1-x_1)+x_2+(1-x_3)+y \ge 1\\
-x_1+x_2-x_3+y \ge -1
$$
and \eqref{5} yields
$$
\lnot (x_1 \land x_2 \land \lnot x_3) \lor y \\
\lnot x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor x_3 \lor y \\
(1-x_1)+(1-x_2)+x_3+y \ge 1\\
-x_1-x_2+x_3+y \ge -1
$$
whereas the valid inequality
$$
-x_1-x_2-x_3+y \ge -1
$$
dominates both of these.  It turns out that a similar strengthening applies to \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}.

---

Here's an alternative approach that yields the strengthened formulation.  Note that $x_2+x_3 \in \{0,1\}$, and introduce binary variable $x_{23}$ to represent $x_2+x_3$.
Now you want to enforce four logical implications:
\begin{align}
(x_1 \land \lnot x_{23}) &\implies \lnot y \tag7\label7 \\
(\lnot x_1 \land x_{23}) &\implies \lnot y \tag8\label8 \\
(x_1 \land x_{23}) &\implies y \tag9\label9 \\
(\lnot x_1 \land \lnot x_{23}) &\implies y \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{align}
Applying conjunctive normal form then yields
\begin{align}
-x_1 + x_{23} - y &\ge -1 \\
 x_1 - x_{23} - y &\ge -1 \\
-x_1 - x_{23} + y &\ge -1 \\
 x_1 + x_{23} + y &\ge  1 
\end{align}
Finally, substituting $x_{23}=x_2+x_3$ yields
\begin{align}
-x_1 + x_2 + x_3 - y &\ge -1 \\
 x_1 - x_2 - x_3 - y &\ge -1 \tag{8'}\label{8'}\\
-x_1 - x_2 - x_3 + y &\ge -1 \tag{9'}\label{9'}\\
 x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + y &\ge  1 
\end{align}
Notice that \eqref{8'} and \eqref{9'} together imply $x_2 + x_3 \le 1$, so you do not need to explicitly enforce that constraint separately.